# Scrolling in steps

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have created a scrolling container with different background colors, and these colors are fadeIn and fadeOut when scrolling. But I want to scroll in steps, for example, when I scroll into the second picture, it could stop, then when scrolling again to third(like fullpagejs). I have checked other post, but I didn't really understand what I should do. Please help..

```js
$(document).scroll(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

if (y >= 100) {
  $('#section2').fadeIn('slow');

} else {
  $('#section2').fadeOut('slow');
};

if (y >= 200) {
  $('#section3').fadeIn('slow');
} else {
  $('#section3').fadeOut('slow');
};

if (y >= 300) {
  $('#section4').fadeIn('slow');
} else {
  $('#section4').fadeOut('slow');
};

});
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color:red;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  height: 738px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}

.slider_sections {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1;
}

#section2{
  background-color: #777;
}

#section3{
  background-color: #eee;
}

#section4{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section3">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section4">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So into your question, I put everything into the snippet and call the jQuery library as it was what was missing to run your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Last thing, even if everything works now, close your last `</div>` tag please. Such as below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section2">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section3">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_sections" id="section4">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
</div> <!-- <---- There -->
```